# Asterisk GotoifTime command from java code

Tags: java, asterisk, asterisk-java

I'm new to asterisk and the world of the PBX in general, 
I wanna use asterisk-java library to communicate with the server through the fastAGI protocol, I could do the basics like answering a phone call and playing something or even jumping in the dial plan using gosub method. My question is that I need the GotoifTime application in my java code, how can I call it from there?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run any asterisk command which do dialplan priority change when you are inside other command(AGI). Actualy you can, but dialplan will go that prio only when you exit AGI.

So you have choose, use dialplan or AGI

You also can choose mixed control by AsyncAGI, but it is REALLY complex variant.